# Application's PagerAdapter changed the adapter's contents without calling notifyDataSetChanged()

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager, notifydatasetchanged

I am developing a simple game on android. I have an activity to fetch data from server and load it into ViewPager. This is the activity code snippet:

```
    url = new ArrayList<>();
    name = new ArrayList<>();
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
    viewPagerAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getApplicationContext(),url,name);
    viewPager.setAdapter(viewPagerAdapter);

    AppController.socket.emit("getDoodle","")
            .on("doodleList", new Emitter.Listener() {
                @Override
                public void call(Object... args) {
                    JSONArray data = (JSONArray)args[0];
                    Log.e("MYTAG",data.toString());
                    url.clear();
                    name.clear();
                    for(int i=0;i<AppController.playersId.size();i++){
                        try {
                            if(!data.getJSONObject(i).getString("doodle").equals("null")) {
                                url.add(data.getJSONObject(i).getString("doodle"));
                                name.add(data.getJSONObject(i).getString("id"));
                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }


                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            viewPagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged;
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
```

This is my PagerAdapter:

```
    class ViewPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

Context mContext;
ArrayList<String> mUri,mId;

public ViewPagerAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> imageUri, ArrayList<String> sid){
    mContext = context;
    mUri = imageUri;
    this.mId=sid;
    Log.e("MYTAG",mUri.toString());
}
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mUri.size();
}

@Override
public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
    return POSITION_NONE;
}

@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, final int position) {
    LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater=(LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View itemView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.pager_child, container, false);

    final ImageView imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.doodleView);
    TextView nameText = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ownerText);
    String temp = mUri.get(position);
    if(!temp.equals("")){
        Log.e("replace","2");
        Glide.with(mContext)
                .load(temp)
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE)
                .into(imageView);
        nameText.setText(mId.get(position));
    }
    Log.d("pager",mUri.get(position));
    itemView.setTag(position);
    container.addView(itemView);
    return itemView;
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
    container.removeView((LinearLayout) object);
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
    return false;
}}
```

My error Log:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                            Process: com.nirup.fuku, PID: 10421
                                                            java.lang.IllegalStateException: The application's PagerAdapter changed the adapter's contents without calling PagerAdapter#notifyDataSetChanged! Expected adapter item count: 0, found: 1 Pager id: com.nirup.fuku:id/viewPager Pager class: class android.support.v4.view.ViewPager Problematic adapter: class com.nirup.fuku.ViewPagerAdapter
                                                                at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1167)
                                                                at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1116)
                                                                at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1642)
                                                                at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19857)
                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6083)
                                                                at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1464)
                                                                at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:758)
                                                                at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:640)
                                                                at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19857)
                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6083)
                                                                at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
                                                                at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:139)
                                                                at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19857)
                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6083)
                                                                at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1464)
                                                                at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:758)
                                                                at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:640)
                                                                at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19857)
                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6083)
                                                                at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
                                                                at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19857)
                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6083)
                                                                at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1464)
                                                                at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:758)
                                                                at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:640)
                                                                at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19857)
                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6083)
                                                                at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
                                                                at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onMeasure(DecorView.java:689)
                                                                at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19857)
                                                                at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2275)
                                                                at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1366)
                                                                at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1619)
                                                                at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1254)
                                                                at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6337)
                                                                at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:874)
                                                                at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:686)
                                                                at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:621)
                                                                at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:860)
                                                                at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong.. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

The problem occurs when the `ViewPager` can not be refreshed during adding items. if the changed count is not equals with saved count you will get this error.

to solve it:

you should call `viewPagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged;` after you change the adapter items..

Code:

```
 public ViewPagerAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> imageUri, ArrayList<String> sid){
    mContext = context;
    mUri = imageUri;
    this.mId=sid;
    notifyDataSetChanged();   //add here
    Log.e("MYTAG",mUri.toString());
}
```

**EDIT**

call `viewPagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`  //you are missing the brackets

Comment: I tried that. I used my exact code as above with notifydatasetchanged() in the constructor.. the app still crashes.. I also tried passing new ViewPagerAdapter object everytime the list changes, but it still crashes

Comment: try extending `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` instead of `PagerAdapter` ..and make sure you call ..`viewPagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`...after you refresh the adapter ...not necessarily passing new ViewPagerAdapter object everytime the list changes... i am just showing an example